# LINQ: how to group by so element can be added to many groups

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have 3 types: `Parameter`, `Facility` and `Location`. `Parameter` has one `Facility` and `Facility` is related many-to-many with `Location`. So, if we make a join, we can get such a table:

```
ParamId FacilityId LocationId
1            1          1
1            1          2
2            2          1
2            2          3
```

Now i want to group my parameters by locations so that i get a Dictionary>, like this:

```
LocationId   Parameters
     1          1,2
     2           1
     3           2
```

I can't do a straight GroupBy because i don't know how to write a keySelector. I Also tried SelectMany like this:

```
parametersList.SelectMany(t=>t.Facility.Locations).GroupBy(t =>t)
.ToDictionary(t=>t.Key, t=>t.Select(val=>val))
```

but it cannot form me my Dictionary..

**Update:**
Here is how my Facility (simplified) looks like:

```
public class Facility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

and here is Location:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
}
```

I'll be gratefull for any help!

Comment: How you define class `Facility` and `Location`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query return that you want:

```
parametersList
        .SelectMany(_ => _.Facility.Locations)
        .GroupBy(_ => _)
        .ToDictionary(
            _ => _.Key, 
            _ => _.SelectMany(l => l.Facilities).SelectMany(f => f.Parameters).Distinct().ToArray());
```

**UPDATE**

You can use `parametersList` or store of parameters for it:

```
parametersList
        .SelectMany(_ => _.Facility.Locations)
        .GroupBy(_ => _)
        .ToDictionary(
            _ => _.Key, 
            _ => _.SelectMany(l => l.Facilities).Select(f => parametersList.Single(p => p.Facility == f)).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: What can i do if my 'Facility' doesn't have 'Parameters' property?